# d3.csv show "XMLHttpRequest cannot load " error

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

In my code I am using `d3.csv`:

```
<head>
   <title>TODO supply a title</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      d3.csv("example.csv", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    </script>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
</body>
```

The CSV is called "example.csv" 
containing:

```
Year    Make
1997    Ford
2000    Mercury
```

But, when I run the program I get the following error message:

> d3.v3.min.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
>   example.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

How can I fixed it?

Comment: Does the URL start with `file://`? If so, your issue is that you need to serve the page to the browser over HTTP. If you have Python installed, `python -mSimpleHTTPServer` is an easy way to start a web server that will serve the content of the current directory.

Comment: i placed the csv file in path:C:\Users\Jeffy\Desktop\Java\GoogleMap

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear: does the URL in the browser's address bar start with `file://`?

Comment: Yes.
Here is the address:
file:///C:/Users/Jeffy/Desktop/Java/GoogleMap/testing.html

Comment: Then my first comment was correct. You'll need to serve the page over HTTP(S).

Comment: do you mean i need to upload my website on server first?

Comment: Actually i want to use read and loop the csv data to my javascript.
How can i do this?

Comment: Try using wamp (windows) or mamp (macOs).

Comment: That would work, but you can also run a web server locally. There are a lot of ways to do that; I mentioned one in my first comment, and @GerardoFurtado mentioned another.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to launch chrome with this option

```
-allow-file-access-from-files
```